# How to use local Typescript definition file for js project in node_modules?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm importing a Javascript package from npm that doesn't have a Typescript definition file anywhere.  I'd like to create a local definition file that I'll eventually PR to DefinitelyTyped or the project itself.

I can't figure out where/how to create and place the definition file such that it will be found locally.

I could copy it into the `node_modules/the-package` directory, but it'll get clobbered during otherwise safe npm operations.

From observing `tsc --traceResolution`, I don't see a good way to do this, unless there's some way to use `types` or `typings` that I haven't figured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a local file with `*.d.ts` and create a module with the same name as your library.

For example, if you were using lodash, you can create typings for it by creating a `d.ts` file:

```
declare module "lodash" {

    interface Lodash {
        map: Function
    }

    var _: Lodash;
    export = _;
}
```

See the [documentation on creating declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html).

Comment: How/where are you declaring your definition files? Can you update your question with a reproducible example?

Answer (score 5):

One of the ways I failed in this was to create a local `*.d.ts` file like this one-line modification of @Saravana's example:

```
import {Component} from 'react'

declare module 'lodash' {

  interface Lodash {
      map: Function
  }

  var _: Lodash;
  export = _;
}
```

This evokes the cryptic error message

`Error:(3, 16) TS2665:Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'lodash' resolves to an untyped module at 'my-project/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js', which cannot be augmented.`

The error made me think that this approach must be wholly wrong, when it's really just complaining about a trivial, easy-to-fix error.  When you `import` in a file, it converts the file into a module, and when Typescript sees a `declare module` inside a module, it assumes you're trying to enhance an existing definition.  The fix is trivial: just move the import inside the `declare` block, like so:

```
declare module 'lodash' {

  import {Component} from 'react'

  interface Lodash {
      map: Function
  }

  var _: Lodash;
  export = _;
}
```

If you use an IDE with auto-import, it will break your definition files in this way every time - remember to move the import!